# ASP.NET to codeigniter

Tags: php, asp.net, codeigniter

I am ASP.NET webforms developer almost 7 years experience. Have done a small ASP.NET MVC project too. Pretty clear with MVC skills

Please advise-

1. Do I need to learn PHP before starting to learn CodeIgniter? I would rate my skills as follows (out of scale of 1-10)
   HTML 6/10
   CSS 4/10
   Javascript 8/10
   JQuery 6/10
   Database 9/10
   MVC understanding 8/10
   Xml/Xslt   8/10
2. Does it make sense to move from .NET to Linux based development?
3. Based on above skill set level. How difficult/easy to move into PHP field

Answer (score 5):

I have 8 years of experience of PHP, and also have 4 years of experience of ASP.NET MVC.

I use CodeIgniter pretty heavily, so I think I know the answer to this question.

1. Yes, you need to know PHP to use CodeIgniter. It's not like ASP.NET where you can jump on it right away, you should probably know how PHP works before getting into CodeIgniter. PHP works differently than ASP.NET, biggest difference is, you don't have Visual Studios.  Also, CodeIgniter MVC works differently than ASP.NET MVC, so I suggest you learn how it works before jumping into it.
2. Moving from .NET to Linux based development is purely based on preference. You can do everything on linux where you can do it on .NET, and vice versa. Microsoft is very competitive in terms of technology, they will always come up with new set of tools to compete with linux products.
3. If you have 7 years of experience with .NET, then why make the switch? PHP/CodeIgniter, like I've said, is very different with ASP.NET/MVC, especially with ASP.NET/WebForms. You will have to make a drastic switch, understand new concepts, just like how you would do when you are learning a new language.

From a programmer's perspective, learning wide, variety of languages and disciplines will make you a better programmer. If it's something that you want to learn, I would suggest try learning it with clean, blank state of mind.

Start with the basics, and broaden your expertise.

Good luck with your journey.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm, I tend to think differently. I have 10 years .net experience, and that includes the web too (HTML ,CSS, Javascript) all versions, and I have been using CodeIgniter and made the jump into the php world.
The Linux world I am familiar with as I have developed Android apps. However, since the advent of ASPNET MVC, and the fact that CodeIgniter is based on the MVC structure (controllers, views and routers), the difference is minimal and is mainly at semantics level(tags etc), and in configurations of an app. However, php is server side code and as such is the same concept as in ASPNET is a mixture of client and server code too.

If you have a good grasp of MVC, and understand client/server code, adding php to you skillset can become a long term advantage. Go for it. PS: CodeIgniter makes the jump pretty easy. Oh, and go to php.net and start coding in php.